# Referring to sects or schools of thought respectfully

Tags: discussion

Since this is a "multi-view" site we need to have certain policies in place to prevent the usage of terms that other Muslims might find offensive when referring to ideologies or schools of though different to one's own. This is simply to **prevent the degeneration of a question or answer into fighting and arguing on a tangential topic**.

What kind of guideline is suitable to achieve this end?

Depending on answers we get and the votes, we'll make this part of the policy for this website and egregious departures from this norm can invite warnings and/or suspensions. We (moderators) feel this is necessary to nip some pointless argumentation in comment threads in the bud.

Answer (score 7):

My suggestion is as follows:

If you're referring to an opinion from another sect and it needs to be identified as such (preferable), try to use **a term the majority among them use to self-identify**. If that is not possible or not sufficient to clearly identify them, use **a term they would not have an objection to**. Finally, if this is entirely too difficult, just use **the name of the scholar whose opinion** is being quoted.

Comment: +1 self-labeling really takes propaganda and agenda-pushing out of the equation, and avoids any possibility of disrespectfully referring to someone.

Comment: I think it is better to refer to the groups/sects/schools using the standard academic terminology, not what they prefer. We may have groups who consider only themselves as (true) Muslims and might oppose using any term other than Muslim and find it offensive. If the used terminology is standard academic terminology there is no point whether some users likes it or not.

Comment: I think this are great salient suggestions. Could you expand with one more point on how you would suggest dealing with people who are seen as different from the outside but categorically object to any/all labels?

Comment: @Kaveh: Would you consider expanding on that just a little and making that an answer here? I think the point you raise is worth the community seriously considering because that approach would foster participation from the kind of people that will best make this a cross-sect _EXPERT_ Q&A site.

Comment: "use a term they would not have an objection to" why if that term is not any disrespect and is a standard term for example in wikipedia?