# Referring to sects or schools of thought respectfully - Part 2

Tags: discussion

This is a follow up of previous discussion on [the topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/331/38). There was requirement for "Part 2" since, one of the users hasn't understood the message or conclusion of the previous discussion. He continues to [call my views as "wahhabi"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2534/what-is-the-justification-of-destroying-shrine-of-imam-sadiq-a-s-but-not-shrine#comment6173_2553) which has a negative connotation. Moreover, I do not self-identify myself as a "wahhabi" nor the scholars I quote or the books I refer. The word doesn't exist in our academic circle.

I've been extremely respectful, tolerant and patient with him. If I wanted, I can use the [term used for shi'a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rafida) in the Sunni theology. It is widely accepted in our books, articles and tapes just like it is acceptable for him to use the term "wahabbi". However, I refrain from using it in order to not offend the Shi'ite sect and for the success of Islam.SE. I continue to advice him. I flag his comments. But, he continues to use it.

Before it gets worse, I think a decision must be made about it.

Comment: We have been struggling with him since the inception of the site. He largely ignores recommendations, whether from mods or otherwise, and flies against norms of the SE platform. It's challenging trying to get someone like that to contribute meaningfully.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you requesting some sort of moderator action, or are you seeking shura from the community?

Comment: why you think I am calling YOUR beliefs? and not wahhabi sect? you have misunderstanding. I am talking about a sect. not you. if you defend wahhabism it includes you and if you do not defend does not include you.

Comment: previous discussion includes different messages. for example look message of Kaveh there. if using a word in this multi-view site of Islam is banned should be clearly mentioned as a rule in FAQ. discussion with different views is different of rule of site.

Comment: @ashes999 I am requesting some sort of decision on this whether by moderator or the community. Whatever is the result, I abide by community guidelines. I just want to get done with it.

Comment: @Ahmadi Because you wrote that on my answer and I answer according to my beliefs.

Comment: i'm really quite shocked to see this question, when i notice that you quote articles in your answers http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/2411/251 that openly insult the Shia's and call them Rafida.

Comment: @Nerrve I never used the word, though. I never complain about the articles that Ahmadi linked or also in his answer. It is about how he uses the comments of others' answers and he uses this word.

Comment: the difference is subtle. To me, when i read those links you posted about the Rafidi Shia, I was offended. Does that mean i should initiate punitive action against you? You chose to categorize me as something that i don't believe in. And you did more than that. Those links also propagate false beliefs about Shias! how should one reconcile with that?

Comment: @Nerrve  You have an option to check those links or leave it alone. I am not responsible to anything in that site that might offend you. Secondly, this is not about answers. It is about comments. The answer is your area where you can say whatever you like and it will be either upvoted or downvoted or deleted. Comments is where you interact with others answer and that is where the problem comes. Again, I reiterate, I never used the term myself in the SE site. To me, that is a big difference.

Comment: @Nerrve And even when I quote from those links, I remove those terms which might offend the Shi'a. As for beliefs, I have provided references for it and there are other Shi'a who differ from your standpoint also. The content of the answer should be judged based on upvotes and downvotes. You might associate certain beliefs, that the sunnis are free from. However, as long as that has references, I see no problems. For example, there are answers of Shi'a that undermines virtues of Aisha. Though I am offended by it, I don't complain.

Comment: @Nerrve And if you want to leave a link to an article that refutes my answer in the comments, you are more than welcome.

Comment: So in short, you don't like comments that refer to you as a Wahhabi. Are there other Sunni's like you who take offense to the word Wahhabi? If that is the case, then it is something that is new to me, since I have always thought of Wahhabism as something that has a different meaning from all the terms associated with it (Salafi etc). And ofc, i will keep it in mind to use the word Wahhabi with caution so that i might not offend anyone. But if it is not the case, and it is only you who are taking offense, then this is not a matter of discussion and should be closed.

Comment: @Nerrve In discussion in chat, there were several people who agree with me that the word Wahhabi shouldn't be used. It is not about me getting offended. But, I think if a term like this is allowed, it opens the door for whole lot of other offending terms out there, which the person who uses it would not have originally intended to use it as a offense.

Comment: i think it would be fair to announce such a agreement that you have had in chat, instead of marginalizing someone who was not aware of the proceedings and who (in the comments below), seemed to indicate that he did not know that Wahabbi is an insult.

Comment: @Nerrve Most of these views have already been expressed in answers by many people - http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/496/should-a-moderator-be-free-to-use-his-power-to-promote-his-own-view, http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/497/sectarianism-and-peaceful-questions-about-disagreements-are-the-same-or-differ, http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/493/is-using-word-wahhabi-banned-in-this-site-why. This issue has been discussed multiple times. He *did* not know Wahabbi was an insult is different from he *does* not agree it to be an insult.

Answer (score 10):

I think main problem here is his understanding of;

> the terms wahhabi is not any kind of insult or rude terms and using it
>   is not disrespect. it simply is the name of sect of Muslims and is a
>   sub-sect of Salafism. wahhabi simply means follower of Muhammad Ibn
>   abd ul-Wahhab.

([source](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/337/44))

On the other hand, any term in itself is a name for something and originally not an insult. With an understanding like this, you can call someone an idiot, and argue that "idiot is not an insult, it is just a name for people who are low on intelligence."

Or yet better, the word Muslim is a beautiful word, we are proud of being called as Muslim. On the other hand, calling people who don't see themselves as Muslims can be seen as insult on their part. They won't care if it is a good thing or not, if they don't see themselves as Muslims, they won't like you calling them one.

So, insulting is not done using **insult words**, but done by associating people with things  that they don't want to be associated with. faq already describes what kind of behavior is expected here;

> Civility is required at all times; rudeness will not be tolerated.
>
> **Be nice**. Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat
>   you. We’re all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may
>   not know everything you know. Bring your sense of humor.

Comment: so how we should call the sect who follow teachings of Muhammad Ibn abdul wahhab? if wahhabi is insult? only tell me name of this sect.

Comment: @Ahmadi You can call them Salafi or Athari or Sunni.

Comment: @Abdullah each of them are different of wahhabi. for example wahhabism is a category of Salafism. using same name for two different things makes confusion. Sunni Islam has many sects like  Mu'tazila, Ash'arites,... if salafi and sunni and wahhabi were same things wikipedia did not make different pages for each of them. I mean what I should call when I want to refer to specific sect who have specific beliefs of wahhabism? while I want only refer to them and not to all sunni sects or non wahhabi salafi. also when I want to refer to sunni or salafi use their own name.

Comment: @Ahmadi I didn't say wahhabi is insult. But appearantly, people don't like to be called as such, you can use whatever they prefer to call themselves, or even say "those who follow Ibn Abdul Wahhab" instead of that spesific term.

Comment: @yasar11732 thanks. interesting suggestion.

Comment: @Ahmadi Non-wahhabi salafi sounds as ridiculous as spicy sugar. Give me one example of salafi scholar who is against Muhammad Ibn Abdul Wahhab. I will give you names of many scholars outside the Saudi who are also salafi at the same time have the same beliefs as Muhammad ibn Abdul wahhab.

Comment: @Abdullah some sources define wahhabism as a branch inside salafism ans some define them the same. http://www.globalsecurity.org/military/intro/islam-salafi.htm I know many scholars out of Saudi Arabia are Salafi specially in Pakistan. but mostly are supported financially by Saudi government.

Comment: @Ahmadi Wahhabi is not a name that we coined. You and the non-muslims invented it. You refer a sect by the name they coined for themselves and what they self-identify as. Why is it so difficult for you to understand? Wahhabi is never used and never was used in any of our books or articles or websites. However, we use salafi quite often. The word wahhabi is used by people other than salafi only. While, shi'ites themselves use the word shi'a and the term is also on your websites.

Comment: @Abdullah is there any problem using words coined by non muslims? TV, internet, many words are coined by non Muslims. is it haram to use such names? why you think I understand difficult. wahhabi exist and you can see in in different sources. many sunni scholars use word wahhabi. and shia widely use this word. example: http://alsunna.org/tzwayraalwahaabyah-watdlyshm-fy-ktaab-Haashyah-aalelamah-aalssaaway-aalmaalky-ela-tfsyr-aaljlalyn.html if you show proof this word is insult I do not use it.